# Como usar FCM firebase cloud menssaging con cordova app híbrida compilar con Phonegap Build

Tags: javascript, phonegap, jquery-mobile, firebase-messaging

Hola estoy haciendo una app híbrida con HTML, CSS, jQuery, jQuery Mobile, apache cordova.
Tengo la duda de como implementar notificaciones push en mi proyecto.
He decidido usar el siguiente plugin cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated pero me da error al compilar con phonegap build.
Dice que falta el archivo google-service.json pero ya lo ingrese a la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: **Solución** **a** **error**  **de** **construcción** Actualice cordova y otros plugin y se fue el error.  **PERO**no consigo recibir notificaciones push con la app cerrada.